# When calling excel file with .open() method, sending a parameter ...how do i manipulate it?

Tags: c#-4.0, excel, vba

I have to open an excel file, with the OPEN method in C#.
In it i wanted to send a parameter (a companyID that i would like to use to filter information  that is displayed in the sheet)
How do i manipulate it with VBA?
I wanted to take that parameter and send it to an sql stored procedure so that the procedure will get some data to populate the sheets , except that with that parameter it would filter it by company, which is what i need to do!
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: If there's code in the workbook which accepts a company Id then you could run it from c# using the Application.Run method.

Comment: what do you mean exactly? the code in the excel workbook has a connection string programmed that calls an sql procedure, and with that, updates data in it. I would like to send this company ID thru C#, youre saying i can use that method? how? thank you so much!

Comment: You'd need a sub in the workbook which takes a company id as a parameter, then uses that to call your sql procedure with that parameter.  You can run that sub using Excel's `Application.Run` method.

Comment: Oh i see, so Id have to call that Application.RUn from the C# code, and send the parameter of the company ID? that way the macro that sets the SQL connection and calls the procedure that populates the workbook is called, and the data is loaded? would there be any other step aside from this? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do what you are asking through VSTO.

With that said, [this site](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_vba-getcommandline/) might help you if you were willing to go the COM route.